# find supress permission errors

Tags: bash, error

Running find command on root folder :

```
find / -type d -wholename "prog" -print
```

Keep seeing errors like

```
find: ./Users/auser/Library/Preferences: Permission denied
```

How can I supress these? If no option in find can you help with a script that greps out the permission messages? Guess need to ignore output that has ": Permission denied" in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the standard Unix way to run any command without the error
messages and without having to take care of their format:

```
find / -type d -wholename "prog" -print 2>/dev/null
```

`2` is the file descriptor on which any command output error messages.

`/dev/null` is a special file like the Trash but without the recovery function of the Desktop one.

`>` means here plug `2` within `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple way would be to run

```
find / -type d -wholename "prog" -print 2>&1 | grep -v ": Permission denied"
```

(which would filter out any folders with "Permission denied" in the name as well, but that's probably not an issue).